# Effect of water viscosity (increased due to NaCl concentration) on dissolution rate of CO2

Tags: water, viscosity

We did an experiment involving different $\ce{NaCl}$ concentration(ranging, 1-4%) on 100 mL of water. Our aim of the experiment was to find the dissolution rate of $\ce{CO2}$in the brine solvent. We did some research and found that $\ce{NaCl}$ increases the viscosity of the solvent, which in-turn decreases the dissolution rate. We want to explain how the entire process works, in a microscopic level.

Answers with good source would be good.

Answer (score 1):

By dissolving NaCl you increase the [ionic strength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength) of the solution, i.e. there is more electrostatic attraction between the layers of water increasing the viscosity. Carbon dioxide is non-polar, so by increasing the polarity of the solvent, the carbon dioxide tend to form less interactions with the solvent.